# Move amount of folders recursive to another folder in the same folder with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, network-drive

I have a root folder (a mapped network drive) to Z, in this folder I have a folder named Archive and I would like to move some folders in Z to archive folder.

The titles of folders to move I have in a csv file.

I've created a PowerShell script, but somehow it does not really work, it does move one folder, but then nothing happens even in the PowerShell command, just empty and after a while nothing happens and I have to close the PowerShell window.

So if I have ten folders to copy only the first is moved and that is it.

Here is the code:

```
$currentPath = Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath;
$areaCsvPath = $currentPath + "\CSVFile.csv";
write-host $areaCsvPath;

$csv = Import-Csv $areaCsvPath;
$count =0;

$Creds = Get-Credential

foreach ($row in $csv)
{
    Get-ChildItem -Path "Z:\" -Recurse |
      Where-Object {$_.name -eq $row.Title} |
      Move-Item -destination "Z:\_Archive" -Credential $Creds

    $count++;
    write-host $count;

}
```

CSV is as follows

```
Title
12345
22223
75687
...
```

Comment: can you provide the `CSVFile.csv`

Comment: Added to the post, but nothing special ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why only one folder gets moved but you could try the following script which should be much faster because the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet is only called once:

```
$currentPath = Split-Path -Parent $PSCommandPath;
$areaCsvPath = $currentPath + "\CSVFile.csv";
write-host $areaCsvPath;

$csv = Import-Csv $areaCsvPath;
$Creds = Get-Credential

Get-ChildItem -Path "Z:\" -Recurse |
      Where-Object Name -in ($csv | select -expand Title) |
      Move-Item -destination "Z:\_Archive" -Credential $Creds
```

If the folders are at the top level on `Z:` you should omit the `-Recurse` parameter. Also if you only want to move folders, you could add the `-Directory` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` invoke to further improve the performance.

Comment: Yes i only need to move folders, but the folders have content, other sub folders and items. Should i remove -recurse and add -directory?

Comment: Yes, give it a try.

Comment: Btw strange i get an error: Move-Item : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. Move-Item -destination "Z:\_Archive";

Comment: Seems like you are missing a backslash there.

Comment: Ok, now it executes, it copies the folders, BUT still the powershell window stops, no new line is coming up for new command to give and the last command 'write-host "Finished" is not displaying, could you know why would this happen? Can it be that there is a lot of folders and this is a mapped network drive?

Comment: Hm, maybe it still copies?

Comment: Thx you were right removing the -Recurce and adding -Directory solved the issue!